# Django-tinymce not loading javascript

Tags: javascript, django, tinymce, tinymce-4, django-tinymce

I have (tried to) set up django-tinymce in my Django project. However, in the inspector, I don’t see the tinymce.min.js being loaded.

This is in my settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
os.environ['DJANGO_LIVE_TEST_SERVER_ADDRESS'] = 'localhost:8123'

# TinyMCE configuration
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, "articles/build/lib/node_modules/tinymce")
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(TINYMCE_JS_ROOT, "tinymce.min.js")
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = False
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': "modern",
    'toolbar': "undo redo | bold italic | bullist numlist | blockquote | removeformat",
    'menubar': False,
    'statusbar': False,
    'schema': "html5",
    'max_height': 500,
    'max_width': 500,
    'min_height': 100,
    'min_width': 400
}
```

Removing the `TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG` and changing `tinymce.min.js` into `tinymce.js` does not change anything—still no tinymce js being loaded.

This is my file structure:

```
static
  |-src
  |  |-styles
  |  |-scripts
  |  |-images
  |-build
  |  |-css
  |  |-js
  |  |-img
  |  |-lib
  |  |  |-package.json
  |  |  |-node_modules
  |  |  |  |-tinymce
  |  |  |  |  |-tinymce.js
  |  |  |  |  |-more_tinymce_files_here
  |-node_modules
  |-gulpfile.js
  |-package.json
```

In my template I do have `{{ form.media }}`, but maybe that‘s the problem.

The [full code with templates, settings, urls, etc. is available here](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/38bbd5fde27904e1ef4d5798eda0ab07).

How can I make sure that the tinymce javascript loads? Or: how can I debug this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the error was in settings.py. The tinymce location needs to be set like this:

```
TINYMCE_JS_ROOT = "articles/build/lib/node_modules/tinymce"
TINYMCE_JS_URL = os.path.join(TINYMCE_JS_ROOT, "tinymce.js")
```

Answer (score 0):

From django-tinymce docs:

> In your own templates containing a TinyMCE widget you must add the following to the HTML HEAD section (**assuming you named your form ‘form’**):

```
<head>
...
{{ form.media }}
</head>
```

Try `{{ articleform.media }}`

Comment: Sadly that doesn’t work. `{{ form }}` is actually the correct way to refer to the form in my templates, though. See [this](https://gist.github.com/Flobin/38bbd5fde27904e1ef4d5798eda0ab07#file-article-submit-form-html-L19) for instance.

Answer (score 0):

Is jQuery available? I added adding your ArticleSubmitView into my working tinymce project, without your tinymce config, and I got an error that jQuery was not defined.  When I added a script tag for jQuery above your `{% block extra_head_stuff %}` tag in base.html, the tinymce editor showed up.

Note that this is with the following, default settings:

```
TINYMCE_SPELLCHECKER = False
TINYMCE_COMPRESSOR = True
TINYMCE_DEFAULT_CONFIG = {
    'theme': "advanced",
    'theme_advanced_buttons3_add': "|,spellchecker",
}
```

Using your settings, I get an error that tinymce.min.js is not found (though this may be due to me not copying over your static setup).